# Whenever/While I am in this district, I go to those restaurants for their food. - different meanings?

Tags: meaning

**Example 1**

> Whenever I am in this district, I go to those restaurants for their food.

**Example 2**

> While I am in this district, I go to those restaurants for their food.

Are both correct English?

Can Example 2 mean the same as Example 1?

Comment: You can look those up.

Answer (score 2):

They are 'correct English' in that there is no grammatical error - BUT...

What would you go to a restaurant for if not for food? I think you mean something like "I go to [a particular type of] restaurant because their food is good".

*Whenever I am in this district* implies that you visit it fairly often, and go to those restaurants every time.

*While I am in this district* implies that you are there now.

Comment: `While I am in this district` might be a bit more ambiguous and context driven. `While I am in this district (points to district on a map) I go to those restaurants, but  while I am in this district (points to another district on the map) I go to those other restaurants`.

Comment: @gingerbreadboy So, "while" can mean the same as "whenever" if the context is clear that I am talking about a habitual thing? For example, "I sing while I shower. That is what I like to do."

Comment: It is not unheard of for people to go to a restaurant for reasons other than the food. For example, a rotating restaurant at the top of a tall tower might well have food that's nothing special, because the people who run the restaurant know people go there for the view, not the food.

Answer (score 2):

In AmE we don't say **whilst** but **while**.   in AmE **while** would not be a perfect substitute for **whenever**.

Using **whenever** means that you *always* go to those restaurants when visting that district. You might have been visiting once a year over many years, or once a month over the past year, the frequency is not specific, but it certainly involves multiple visits.

**while** sounds a little off to my ear. Absent other clues in the sentence about how much you like *The Blue Duck*, for whatever reason (prices, convenience, food, ambience, friendliness of the other diners) **while** wouldn't have nearly the force of **whenever** in a restaurant review:

> I eat at *The Blue Duck* whenever I am in the area.
>
> I eat at *The Blue Duck* while I am in the area.

There are connotative differences.